# Yes value returned in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm starting to learn prolog for a course, and I cant get my head around why I dont get what I expect.
I have the following facts:

```
in_queue(Person, I, PersonBefore).
in_queue(adi, 1, null).
in_queue(rami, 1, adi).
in_queue(yael, 1, rami).
in_queue(yuval, 1, yael).
in_queue(dana, 2 , null).
in_queue(tzvi, 2, dana).
in_queue(alon, 2, tzvi).
in_queue(vered, 2, alon).
in_queue(david, 2, vered).
```

and I need to make a predicate `touch(Name1, Name2)` where touch means if `name1` is before or after `name2`, e.g. `rami` touches `adi` and `yael`.

When i do `touch(rami, ddd)` it says yes, and i dont get why because its not in the facts.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `in_queue(Person, I, PersonBefore)` will succeed for any values of its arguments since `Person`, `I`, and `PersonBefore` are all variables.

Comment: Lurker is spot on with his comment, but why did you think it wasn't relevant to post `touch/2`?

Comment: ive no idea what touch/2 mean. so how can i tell if ddd exists within the facts or not?

Comment: I'm guessing there may be no `touch/2` predicate and OP is querying a term `touch(rami,ddd)` which obviously returns true? Instead of writing your top line, which as @lurker pointed out, will always succeed, what you want is to define a predicate which pattern matches on the names you supply it via a query. So in code: `touch(X,Y) :- in_queue(X,_,Y) ; in_queue(Y,_,X).`, which says that if X comes before Y in the queue OR (`;` operator) the other way around, then X and Y touch each other.

Comment: @Infested `touch/2` is the common notation to mean *"binary (i.e. with 2 arguments) predicate named `touch`"*. which is what you're using when you call `touch(rami, ddd)`. and if you get "yes" back, it means, it is defined *somewhere*. --- your very first line was probably intended as a comment, so, must start with `%`.

Comment: I think @WillNess is right, what does _ mean? and why cant I use any upcase letter here (by that I mean, when do I use a _ and when do I use an upper case letter?)? on the original question, what does having a fact mean if I dont have its blueprint? (like a method signature)

Comment: 1. this is very basic Prolog stuff, do read some tutorial; 2. _ is an unnamed unique logical variable; 3. upper case letter is a named logvar, and you use it when you use it in more than one place, so you use same name in both (all) places; 4. Prolog predicates have no declarations; 5. see 1., please. :)